# Spark dataframe caching by executing multiple queries in different threads

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know if dataframe caching in spark is thread-safe. In one of our use cases, I am creating a dataframe from a hive-table, and then running multiple SQL on same dataframe by different threads. Since our storage and compute are decoupled, and the reads are very slow for some reason, I was thinking of caching the dataframe in memory and utilising the cached dataframe for all the queries. Is dataframe caching thread-safe? Are there any other pitfalls in doing so?
I have sufficient memory (disk and RAM) in my compute cluster to cache the table, and I will be executing 10+ queries on the same dataframe.

Thanks,

Akash

Answer (score 0):

Re:"I want to know if dataframe caching in spark is thread-safe."

Whenever you configure executor cores, you are in a way using multiple threads to process the data on each executor. This means in a normal SPARK SQL scenario as well DAG is processed using multiple threads.

Caching should not have any impact towards thread safety. Moreover DataFrames as well are immutable as RDD hence you are not changing data in existing dataframe but you are producing a new one.

Hence even after caching when you create multiple threads to run different SQLs on the same dataframe, every thread would start from the cached stage and compute a new one based on your SQL.